# create variable in makefile that renders and moves output to new subdirectory

Tags: r, makefile, rstudio

Using a makefile with Rstudio, I will generate an html report from an Rmd file in my analysis/ subdirectory using the variable $(RENDER), and then I will move this html report to the reports/ subdirectory in the next line of the make rule.

```
# define VARIABLES for Makefile
RENDER = Rscript -e "require(rmarkdown); render('$<')" 
DAT = ./data
ANL = ./analysis
REP = ./reports

VPATH = $(DAT) $(ANL) $(REP)

# generate a report in html
foo.html: foo.Rmd bar.rds
    $(RENDER)
    mv foo.html $(REP)
```

How can I combine these two steps into one variable command?

```
# Attempt: 
RENDREP = $(RENDER); mv $($< : .Rmd=.html) $(REP)

# generate a report in html
    foo.html: foo.Rmd bar.rds
        $(RENDREP)
```

My attempt at the RENDREP variable yields this error message:

```
Output created: foo.html
usage: mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source target
       mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source ... directory
make: *** [foo.html] Error 64
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax of `$($< : .Rmd=.html)` is wrong, it should be

```
RENDREP = $(RENDER); mv $(<:.Rmd=.html) $(REP)
```

That said, it'd be simpler to just do

```
RENDREP = $(RENDER); mv $@ $(REP)
```

Comment: your first variable works perfectly, but the second variable requires that I add "$(ANL)/" before "$@" in order to work. Thank you for both solutions.

Comment: @Joe Then the rule should be `$(ANL)/foo.html: foo.Rmd bar.rds`